# Visual Studio 2012 Nuget Update Packages keep redownloading

Tags: visual-studio-2012, package, nuget

**Using:** Visual Studio 2012 ultimate with Update 4
**Problem:** Every time I use update-package, it redownloads the same version.
**Scenario:** 
1. I fire up VS2012, make new project Asp.NET MVC4 Web Application -> Internet Application. 
2. I type 'update-package' in package manager console. Downloads every package update. I save the solution. Exit. 
3. I create a new project Asp.NET MVC4 Web Application -> Internet Application. 
4. Since packages are not updated, I type 'update-package' again.
But when I do, it will DOWNLOAD again the SAME version that I already downloaded during my first project.

My problem is, I am not always connected to the internet so do I have to find internet connection everytime I 'update-package' to update the template.

Is there a way I can save the package updates locally so when I do 'update-package' I dont have to be connected to the internet to update all the packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create folder for nuget packages, for example `D:\NugetLocalSource\`, and add specify it as package source in nuget settings. `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Packages Manager Settings -> Package Sources -> Add`.

When you updated packages first time they were downloaded to `solution_folder\packages\`. You can copy `*.nupkg` files from `packages` folder to you local source and then will you be able use them offline for other solutions.
Or you can pre-download packages from nuget.org another way.

One more place where you can find downloaded packages locally - it's nuget cache. It's placed in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`. [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx) is nice article about how to use it